# Angular `orderBy` filter issue with predicate array

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

It seems either there is an issue in angular orderBy filter or I am missing something
I want to order by multiple properties hence passing all the properties as array of strings preceded by `+` or `-`strings.
I have a method `getPredicate()` which parse the `filterObject` and creates array of predicates (keys in `filterObject`). based on value of each key in `filterObject` it precede each predicate with `+` or `-` sign.
(since object properties are dynamic and it is quite possible property name contain space in between like `Updated Date` it is necessary to enclose them with `'`)
it seems sorting is not accurate. initial predicate would look like `["'name'", "'-Updated Date'"]`.

here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/93vgUTBVh3LV7g1ooLgi?p=preview) I have forked.

Comment: would it be possible to add some code?

Comment: @AniruddhaDas: I have added link to plunker

Comment: Remove those single quotes. The key is *name*, not *'name'*.

Comment: @JBNizet: well they need to be there in case if I got some property like "Created Date", those properties are dynamic and it is possible having property with space in between, this is what angular instruct to do https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 0):

Solution for those who have similar issue,

you have to prefix `-` or `+` sign before `' (single quote)` in order to make it work, I was facing issue since I was trying to prefix `-` or `+` sign after `' (single quote)` so console printed array will look something like `["+'name'", "-'Updated Date'", "-'city'"]` and it work perfectly.

working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jIOaPPY6zR9iFR4UgrNq?p=preview)