# How to create array of string with each string enclosed with single quote(javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have an object which I am iterating through it's key and pushing all of its key in an array, I need to enclose each string with single quote, so for example if I have an object `{"name": true, "Updated Date": false}` I want to create array of string as ['"name"', '"Updated Date"'], The reason behind requiring this format is to make angular orderBy filter work with multiple predicate an each predicate having space in between like **Updated Date**

I had tried following code

```js
var myObj = {"name": true, "Updated Date": false}

var myPredicates = [];

for(var prop in myObj) {
    myPredicates.push("'" + prop + "'");
}

console.log(myPredicates);
```

doing that the result will be `["'name'", "'Updated Date'"]` but what I want to achieve is `['"name"', '"Updated Date"']`

here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/93vgUTBVh3LV7g1ooLgi?p=preview) I am trying to make `predicate` from `filterObject`

Comment: If it's just an object I think Object.keys(myObj) would give you what you want.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Is myObj an array... Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

The question you are asking here--which the other answers have taken at face value and given reasonable answers--is **not** the question you mean to ask, based on your actually AngularJS code in your plunkr. On top of that, you have a couple misconceptions about JavaScript that are causing you further confusion:

1. Whether you have single quotes inside double quotes or
   double quotes inside single quotes *does not matter*.
2. When you print a string to the console in a browser it *always* uses double
   quotes (try just typing both `'abc'` <kbd>return</kbd> and `"abc"`
   <kbd>return</kbd> in your console directly to see this).

So as to your actual problem: rather than this...

```
predicate=['"+name"','"-Updated Date"']
```

what AngularJS requires is this...

```
predicate=['+"name"','-"Updated Date"']
```

Notice the placement of the plus and minus signs have changed. (As you likely know, the quotes are not actually needed around `name` because it has no embedded spaces, but it does not hurt to have them there, as your code does.)

Thus, your plunkr code, instead of this:

```
predicate.push("'-" + key + "'");
```

should use:

```
predicate.push("-'" + key + "'");
```

Comment: Agree, It was my misconception and I think all the answers are correct in their place, I have noticed my mistake yesterday and even I answered my own question about angular `orderBy` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623608/angular-orderby-filter-issue-with-predicate-array?noredirect=1#comment70448916_41623608
As you said my `+` and `-` sign placement was wrong but not to quote positions

Answer (score 0):

Just add the escaped quotation marks.

```js
var myObj = {"name": true, "Updated Date": false}

var myPredicates = [];

for(var prop in myObj) {
    myPredicates.push('"\'' + prop + '\'"');
}

console.log(myPredicates[0]);
console.log(myPredicates[1]);
```

Comment: This will add another pair of " to my string `[""name"", ""Updated Date""]`, and it is necessary to enclose `"Updated Date"` with single quote like `'"Updated Date"'`

Comment: Its called Escaping characters, in this case quotes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry mate, but still I did not understood the relation of the link you provided with this issue, I have provided a plunker, if we try to use the solution that I created or you suggest or Jhon, non will work, the reason for example for you solution is there is no property in my data called `""name""` so sort will not work as expected, angular filter accept array of property name `["name", "city"]` and it will sort the data base on these two properties, now the reason we need to enclose the strings with single quote is space between `Updated` and `date` fo such properties...

Comment: ..[continuation of previous comment]
which have space in between, they need to be enclosed with pair of single quote now your solution will create an string like `""Updated Date""` and there is no such property in our data and my solution creates `"'Updated Date'"` and there is no `'Updated Date'` in data so sorting wont work, sorry for long explanation, I just wanted to make you familiar to what problem exactly I am facing, I think I need to either contact angular team or write my own sorting functionality

Comment: how are you taking the array produced here and trying to set the sorting on the angular page?

Comment: Also if you can provide a working plunker with a hard coded version, then people could see what the outcome is supposed to look like.

Comment: Well yesterday I realize my mistake and it was not about how should the quotes be places but the placement of `+` and `-` signs matters and that was creating problem, here is working plunker with expected result :
https://plnkr.co/edit/jIOaPPY6zR9iFR4UgrNq?p=preview

Comment: great I'm glad you got it running,  thanks for the working link, it helps me understand angular

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Note I only print one element because console.log(keys) seems to format the strings in the array to look differently.

```js
var myObj = {"name": true, "Updated Date": false}

var keys = Object.keys(myObj);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i] = "'\"" + keys[i] + "\"'";
}

console.log(keys[0]);
```

Comment: well it wont help, since the version in array are look like `["'"name"'", "'"Updated Date"'"]` and if we try it on the plunker I provided to sort the data, the sorting result is not correct since the result is not as expected

Answer (score 0):

Why do not just invert **double quote "** with **single quote '**

```
    var myObj = {"name": true, "Updated Date": false}

    var myPredicates = [];

    for(var prop in myObj) {
        myPredicates.push('"' + prop + '"');
    }


    for (var i=0; i<myPredicates.length; i++){
        console.log (myPredicates[i])
    }

//"name"
//"Updated Date"
```